# Django path('challenges/',include(challenges.urls)) NameError: name 'challenges' is not defined

Tags: python, django, path

## When I comment

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   #path('challenges/',include(challenges.urls))
]
```

it is working fine but for

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('challenges/',include(challenges.urls))
]
```

it is throwing `an` error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L90FK.png)

why the error is occurring when  I am using

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('challenges/',include(challenges.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write like this in quotes,

```
path('challenges/',include("challenges.urls"))
```

Comment: it solved my problem by now but now when I am using
"python manage.py runserver"

it is throwing this error
Using the URLconf defined in months.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: admin/ challenges/ The empty path didn’t match any of these.

Comment: you have to do this for empty path, In your root urls.py file do this, path('',include("challenges.urls")) and in your challenges.urls file you have to add this pattern in your urlpatterns list path('', views.index, name='index'),

Comment: Thanks, it got solved with
 
path("", views.hello_world)